# Sharing frozensets if they are equal

Tags: python, caching

While forming a dictionary, I have a lot of equal frozensets to become dictionary values. So, I would like to share equal frozensets.

Here is one of possible solutions:

```
result = dict()
helper = dict()
for key, value in generate_data():  # generate_data will return a lot of equal frozensets as values
    result[key] = helper.setdefault(value, value)
```

In this solution `helper` dictionary is used to find out if the current `frozenset` has already equal `frozentset` seen before ans saved in the `helper`, and if not - save it there. All the hard work is done by `setdefault`.

What I don't like about this solution is that it is very difficult to understand at once (nontrivial usage of `setdefault`)

So, my question is:
Can it be written in more readable and understandable way, still as concise (or nearly concise) as this solution?

Comment: You could sort the result of `generate_data` by the `values` and then use `itertools.groupby` to group on the value.  (I think that would work ...)  Of course, that turns an O(N) algorithm into an O(NlogN) one ...

Comment: And do you really have enough frozensets to make a difference?  The only reason to care about this the I can think of is memory consumption... How much memory are you actually using here?

Comment: @mgilson Yes, it's about memory. The formed dictionary will leave in the memory for a long time. I don't want to consume memory without a good reason. Now it can be solved with one-liner! (still not a very readable one).

Answer (score 1):

the implementation isn't going to vary, but if you don't like actually seeing the helper dict:

```
class Cache(object):
    __slots__ = ['helper']

    def __init__(self):
        self.helper = dict()

    def __call__(self, hashable):
        return self.helper.setdefault(hashable, hashable)
```

you would use it like this:

```
result = dict()
cached = Cache()
for key, value in generate_data():  # generate_data will return a lot of equal frozensets as values
    result[key] = cached(value)
```

this shouldn't use any less memory than the other solution, but maybe syntactically it's a little better looking.

edit: just wanted to add, this also allows something like:

```
result = dict((key, cached(value)) for key, value in generate_data())
```

or

```
result = {key:cached(value) for key, value in generate_data()}
```

if you're in python 2.7+.

Answer (score 0):

```
if value not in helper:
    helper[value] = value
result[key] = helper[value]
```

Comment: Could we do without `helper` dict, which duplicates `frozenset`s storing it as key and value altogether?

Comment: @ovgolovin `value` is being used for both key and value when stored; what makes you think it's duplicated?

Comment: Use a `set`, it stores only unique items.(equivalent to value-less dictionary)

Comment: @hcwhsa But how then I can the existing frozenset object from `set`? Theoretically we can calculate hash of that frozenset and then locate existing frozenset in the dict, but I don't see how it can be done with Python `set` interface.

Comment: @ovgolovin http://ideone.com/9LMUE4 (As I said sets are nothing but key-less dicts only and can store any immutable(hashable) item)

Comment: http://ideone.com/AKAnNi How can we get `a` from `s` when we see that `b` is in `s`?

Comment: yeah, you can't use a set - you can verify that newitem b is identical to olditem a that's already in there - but they are still two separate objects. you really want to throw away newitem b and return a reference to the olditem a.